# Sending SOAP Requests With C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529276.aspx) tutorial on how to send a SOAP message via C#, and have reached this stage:

**Program**

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Messaging;

namespace SOAP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri strEpr = new Uri("http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL");
            EndpointReference epr = new EndpointReference(strEpr);

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(epr);
        }
    }
}
```

**TcpClient**

```
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Messaging;

namespace SOAP
{
    class TcpClient : SoapClient
    {
        public TcpClient(EndpointReference endpointreference)
        {
            SoapClient();
        }

        [SoapMethod("RequestResponseMethod")]
        public SoapEnvelope RequestResponseMethod(SoapEnvelope envelope)
        {
            return base.SendRequestResponse("RequestResponseMethod", envelope);
        }
    }
}
```

However, in the constructor in my TcpClient class I am seeing this error:

`Non-invocable member 'SoapClient' cannot be used like a method.`

I can see why this is, because the SoapClient class is abstract and its constructors are all protected. Does this mean that the MSDN documentation is out of date, or am I missing something here?

All I need to do is send a SOAP message to a web service and get the response - surely this should be quite easy in C#?

Comment: Did you notice the date in that article? I am sure there are loads of good newer tutorials on SOAP. .NET does not promote SOAP anymore. The new framework is called WCF.

Comment: Ah thanks for the tip Kosala. Can I still send normal requests to WSDL as we do with soap using WCF?

Comment: Yes you can. There is no change in the basic concept.

Comment: Thanks Kosala, I added an answer showing how I resolved this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per `Kosala W`'s recommendation, I found a solution to this without using SOAP messaging.

1. Right click the project in the Solution Explorer and select `Add` -> `Service Reference`.
2. In the dialog, type in the WSDL address and give it a name . This generates some tags in the `app.config` file with details about the Endpoint entered.
3. The service reference can now be called in the code. For example, if I created a Service Reference called `Darwin`, I can now call the methods associated with this web service like this:

   ```
   Darwin.LDBServiceSoapClient client = new Darwin.LDBServiceSoapClient();
   Darwin.StationBoard myBoard = client.GetDepartureBoard(params, go, here);
   ```

Where the client is used to send the message, and the `GetDepartureBoard` performs some operation on the web server (In this case, the method retrieves data about the specified Train Times Departure Board and returns it in SOAP message format).

Thanks Kosala w!

Answer (score 1):

Although you now use a different approach, the problem with your posted code is that you didn't call the base classes constructor.

You should have done it like so

```
public TcpClient(EndpointReference endpointreference)
    : base(endpointreference)
{}
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I did not realise that it needed the : base keyword! I will probably stick with the other method as I read somewhere that it is preferred, but this will help me in the future!